# Vertical Centering in a multicols

Tags: floats, lists, vertical-alignment, multicol

In a document I have several `multicols` units, in which on one side there is an image and on the other side some information in a `itemize`.

Now, depending on the image / information, the two "sections" vary in their vertical size. Is there a possibility to center both parts inside that `multicols` unit?

For example I have

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
   \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{1bitalu.png}
    \end{figure}

    \vfill
    \columnbreak

    \begin{itemize}
        \item "Arithmetic Logical Unit" für mehrere Rechenarten
        \item Addition, Subtraktion, logisches AND / OR, Vergleich etc.
        \item Parallele "Berechnung" aller Operationen
        \item Selektion mit einem "Multiplexer"
        \item Selektion durch die Kontrolleinheit (Control Unit)
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

which results in

[image]

but I want to have it like this

[image]

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are two options, using [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) or [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `m{<len>}` column specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,multicol}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \null \vfill
  \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-a}

  \vfill \null    
  \columnbreak

  \begin{itemize}
    \item ``Arithmetic Logical Unit'' f\"ur mehrere Rechenarten
    \item Addition, Subtraktion, logisches AND / OR, Vergleich etc.
    \item Parallele ``Berechnung'' aller Operationen
    \item Selektion mit einem ``Multiplexer''
    \item Selektion durch die Kontrolleinheit (Control Unit)
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\columnsep}m{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\columnsep}@{}}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ``Arithmetic Logical Unit'' f\"ur mehrere Rechenarten
    \item Addition, Subtraktion, logisches AND / OR, Vergleich etc.
    \item Parallele ``Berechnung'' aller Operationen
    \item Selektion mit einem ``Multiplexer''
    \item Selektion durch die Kontrolleinheit (Control Unit)
  \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

An `m{<len>}` column specification centers its content by placing the "anchor" in the middle vertically.

Comment: What is `\null` doing?

Comment: @azetina: `\null` is defined in the LaTeX kernel [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) as `\def\null{\hbox{}}`. It initiates horizontal mode, and therefore puts something on a line. Since vertical filling sometimes require "end points" in order to stretch, using `\null` is a viable option. It may not be necessary here, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: What other possibilities are there? Is `\leavevmode` one?

Comment: @azetina: You can use `\leavevmode`, or `\mbox{}`. Not sure whether this answers your question.

Comment: @Werner this is technically not quite correct: \null does *not* initiate horizontal mode, it stays in whatever mode you are in. All it does is to add an empty \hbox to the current mode which in this case is v-mode. It works alright in this case but this fact makes it a bit dangerous. The "LaTeX" way would probably be \vspace*{\stretch{1}} or \mbox{}\vfill