# Problem picture with text

Tags: graphics, multicol

I'm trying to put some text (more exactly a bullet list) next to an image. At first I was using the wrapfigure package but saw that it was not suitable for bulleted lists. So I tried with a multicol but I have a problem because my text starts at the bottom of the image before moving to the side. How can I solve my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}
\textbf{Principe du programme} :
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{47}]
\item on alimente en 0V la broche D3 à l’aide de digitalWrite ce qui permet de décharger le condensateur ;
\item on appelle la fonction réglage qui permet de récupérer les données d'acquisition ;
\item tant que l'on a pas atteint le nombre de points de mesure (test avec if), on appelle la fonction lecture qui vérifie que :
    \begin{itemize}[label=\ding{49}]
    \item le condensateur est bien déchargé (test avec while), applique une tension de 5V à la broche D3 à l'aide de digitalWrite pour commencer la charge du condensateur et démarre le compteur en notant le temps de départ à l’aide de millis ;
    \item si la valeur lue aux bornes du condensateur (borne A0), test avec if, est supérieure à 63 \% de la valeur maximale (en analogique 10 bit, la valeur maximale est 1023 donc quand la valeur atteint 674), on arrête le compteur en notant la valeur de millis ;
    \end{itemize}
\item on écrit dans le moniteur série avec Serial.println le temps écoulé entre le départ et l'arrivée en le convertissant en secondes et on remet à 0V la tension aux bornes du circuit pour le décharger.
\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could use two minipages, one for the image, tge secon one for the text.

Comment: What about a `\columnbreak` after the image?  BTW, for the width of the image use some like  `.9\linewidth` instead of a absolute measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use minipages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,pifont,enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{6.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-6.5cm-\columnsep}
\textbf{Principe du programme} :
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{47}]
\item on alimente en 0V la broche D3 à l’aide de digitalWrite ce qui permet de décharger le condensateur ;
\item on appelle la fonction réglage qui permet de récupérer les données d'acquisition ;
\item tant que l'on a pas atteint le nombre de points de mesure (test avec if), on appelle la fonction lecture qui vérifie que :
    \begin{itemize}[label=\ding{49}]
    \item le condensateur est bien déchargé (test avec while), applique une tension de 5V à la broche D3 à l'aide de digitalWrite pour commencer la charge du condensateur et démarre le compteur en notant le temps de départ à l’aide de millis ;
    \item si la valeur lue aux bornes du condensateur (borne A0), test avec if, est supérieure à 63 \% de la valeur maximale (en analogique 10 bit, la valeur maximale est 1023 donc quand la valeur atteint 674), on arrête le compteur en notant la valeur de millis ;
    \end{itemize}
\item on écrit dans le moniteur série avec Serial.println le temps écoulé entre le départ et l'arrivée en le convertissant en secondes et on remet à 0V la tension aux bornes du circuit pour le décharger.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of `adjustbox` you can get top alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,pifont,enumitem}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{flushleft}

\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=t]{example-image}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-6.5cm-\columnsep}
\textbf{Principe du programme} :
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{47}]
\item on alimente en 0V la broche D3 à l’aide de digitalWrite ce qui permet de décharger le condensateur ;
\item on appelle la fonction réglage qui permet de récupérer les données d'acquisition ;
\item tant que l'on a pas atteint le nombre de points de mesure (test avec if), on appelle la fonction lecture qui vérifie que :
    \begin{itemize}[label=\ding{49}]
    \item le condensateur est bien déchargé (test avec while), applique une tension de 5V à la broche D3 à l'aide de digitalWrite pour commencer la charge du condensateur et démarre le compteur en notant le temps de départ à l’aide de millis ;
    \item si la valeur lue aux bornes du condensateur (borne A0), test avec if, est supérieure à 63 \% de la valeur maximale (en analogique 10 bit, la valeur maximale est 1023 donc quand la valeur atteint 674), on arrête le compteur en notant la valeur de millis ;
    \end{itemize}
\item on écrit dans le moniteur série avec Serial.println le temps écoulé entre le départ et l'arrivée en le convertissant en secondes et on remet à 0V la tension aux bornes du circuit pour le décharger.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Partly considering  @Fran comment, partly @Werner [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86452/vertical-centering-in-a-multicols):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

    \begin{multicols}{2}
\null \vfill    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86452/
\noindent%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}

\vfill \null 
\columnbreak

\textbf{Principe du programme} :
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{47}]
\item on alimente en 0V la broche D3 à l’aide de digitalWrite ce qui permet de décharger le condensateur ;
\item on appelle la fonction réglage qui permet de récupérer les données d'acquisition ;
\item tant que l'on a pas atteint le nombre de points de mesure (test avec if), on appelle la fonction lecture qui vérifie que :
    \begin{itemize}[label=\ding{49}]
    \item le condensateur est bien déchargé (test avec while), applique une tension de 5V à la broche D3 à l'aide de digitalWrite pour commencer la charge du condensateur et démarre le compteur en notant le temps de départ à l’aide de millis ;
    \item si la valeur lue aux bornes du condensateur (borne A0), test avec if, est supérieure à 63 \% de la valeur maximale (en analogique 10 bit, la valeur maximale est 1023 donc quand la valeur atteint 674), on arrête le compteur en notant la valeur de millis ;
    \end{itemize}
\item on écrit dans le moniteur série avec Serial.println le temps écoulé entre le départ et l'arrivée en le convertissant en secondes et on remet à 0V la tension aux bornes du circuit pour le décharger.
\end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
\lipsum[12]

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Other possibility, where is simple possibility to change column width, is use table, for example of the `tabularx` type:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} cX @{}}
\includegraphics[width=56mm, valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    &   \textbf{Principe du programme}:
        \begin{itemize}[label=\ding{47}]
    \item on alimente en 0V la broche D3 à l’aide de digitalWrite ce qui permet de décharger le condensateur ;
    \item on appelle la fonction réglage qui permet de récupérer les données d'acquisition ;
    \item tant que l'on a pas atteint le nombre de points de mesure (test avec if), on appelle la fonction lecture qui vérifie que :
            \begin{itemize}[label=\ding{49}]
        \item le condensateur est bien déchargé (test avec while), applique une tension de 5V à la broche D3 à l'aide de digitalWrite pour commencer la charge du condensateur et démarre le compteur en notant le temps de départ à l’aide de millis ;
        \item si la valeur lue aux bornes du condensateur (borne A0), test avec if, est supérieure à 63 \% de la valeur maximale (en analogique 10 bit, la valeur maximale est 1023 donc quand la valeur atteint 674), on arrête le compteur en notant la valeur de millis ;
            \end{itemize}
    \item on écrit dans le moniteur série avec Serial.println le temps écoulé entre le départ et l'arrivée en le convertissant en secondes et on remet à 0V la tension aux bornes du circuit pour le décharger.
    \end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that I feel like I can't change the width of the columns

Comment: If the problem is width of columns, than this approach is not what you looking for. This is not clear from your question. I will add another solution asap.

Comment: @Nicolas, see addendum In it is solution with use of table.

Comment: this is nice !
Can you explain to me :
- the parameter {m{#1}} in tabularxcolumns 
- the parameter {@{} cX @{} in tabular
- what is the & in front of the \ \textbf
Thanks

Comment: @Nicolas, default are X cells equivalent to `p{...}` type of cells (with features that width is calculated by LaTeX), with `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` is `p` type replaced with`m` type, which vertically center cells' contents. By @{} are nullify columns separations. In your case at left and right border of table. To observe this, make a test with given MWE where delete tem in column specification and them observe difference. `& is marker for columns, `\textbf{...}` is command for boldface text inside braces.

Comment: @Nicolas, I suggest you to read some introductory text abot LaTeX, for example http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.